# Upgrading NuGet version in solution

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

We have NuGet configured for our solution. There is a `.nuget` folder containing configuration but also `NuGet.exe` file. I just noticed that this file is really out of date (2.0 version). How can I upgrade it? Should I copy a later version over it? But where can I find the executable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the command `nuget.exe update -self`

check nuget [Update Command](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference#Update_Command) documentaton

Answer (score 2):

just add a prebuildevent that exec:

```
nuget.exe update -self
```

this will check and update if needed nuget on every build or you can call it manually from the command prompt when you want to update it.

The update process is very fast and nuget will download the new version into the `.nuget` folder and rename the old `nuget.exe` to `nuget.exe.old` so you can eventually rollback the update.

The only "problem" in using the prebuildevent is that the nuget.exe will disappear from the visualstudio solution folder `.nuget`. This happens also if you run the prompt command with visualstudio open in that solution/projects
[nuget Update Command documentaton](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference#Update_Command)

Comment: I am pretty sure that I don't want to have it as a pre-build event :) Did the job from the command line though, cheers!